# Modifying the time function in C

Tags: c, time, casting

For a computer security assignment, I have to modify the time function in order to return a specific date. I need the time function to return a date between Jan 1st, 2016 and June 15th, 2018. I then use these commands to overload and hook into the time function:

```
gcc -Wall -fPIC -shared -o newtime.so newtime.c -ldl
export LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/newtime.so
```

Here is my modified version of the time function:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <time.h>

time_t time (time_t *t)
{
    long int seconds = 1485907200;
    time_t modifiedTime = (time_t) seconds;
    return modifiedTime;
}
```

Whenever I run this implementation, it says that the date being returned is December 31, 1969 19:00:00. Am I just formatting the time since the Linux Epoch incorrectly or am I making a more serious mistake? I have tried using a regular int instead of a long int, and still experience the same issues. Some insight into my mistake would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not implementing the entire functionality of `time()`.  The code your interposing on may use functionality that you have not implemented.

[Per the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.27.2.4):

> **7.27.2.4 The time function** (note the bolded part):
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
>      #include <time.h>
>      time_t time(time_t *timer);
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> The time function determines the current calendar time. The encoding
>   of the value is unspecified.
>
> **Returns**
>
> The time function returns the implementation's best approximation to
>   the current calendar time. The value (time_t)(-1) is returned if the
>   calendar time is not available. **If timer is not a null pointer, the
>   return value is also assigned to the object it points to.**

A full implementation, based on your code:

```
time_t time (time_t *t)
{
    long int seconds = 1485907200;
    time_t modifiedTime = (time_t) seconds;

    if ( t )
    {
        *t = modifiedTime;
    }

    return modifiedTime;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that actually fixed my issue. It makes sense to me as well. I wasn’t getting passed a null so it defaulted to time implementation

Answer (score 0):

In fact, there is no problem in the code that you presented. I tested it with the following basic program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%ld\n", (long) time(NULL));
}
```

So I just run `LD_PRELOAD=./newtime.so ./test` and I get the expected result.

However, the `date` command doesn't make call to the `time` function. It calls instead `int clock_gettime(clockid_t clk_id, struct timespec *tp)`. So you should better re-implement them both if you would like to cover this case.

May be a simple implementation like the following one (It works fine with `date`):

```c
int clock_gettime(clockid_t clk_id, struct timespec *tp)
{
    if(tp) {
        tp->tv_sec = 1485907200;
        tp->tv_nsec = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you get a date different from your expectation, it could be related to your time zone.